# Visual Studio 2015 Community not responding to mouse clicks

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, freeze

I have installed Visual Studio recently but I can't use it. The program opens but I can't click on anything. It looks like the whole window is inactive (gray icon and text in top left corner). I have tried to reinstall it, however, that doesn't work. And if I click on the window, a sound appears (but it's not the error one, probably a warning one). Any suggestions?

edit: I have to close it through task manager. I can't even close it by clicking on the VS 2015 icon at Windows bar and selecting "close program" item in menu

[image]

edit2: If I click on the VS2015 window and then type on my keyboard, the weird "dong" sound appears. Same if I just click on the window. However, sometimes I can navigate using keyboard and therefore open window for starting new project. In this window I can use mouse absolutely normally, however, if I click on the OK button, the window quickly close and reopen again. It won't create a new project. So I'm still stuck on the welcome screen.

edit3: Another interesting thing I found. Now when I click on the OK button this error [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7mic.png) appears. Should I reinstall it again (for 3rd time), and hope that this time it will be installed right?

PS: I'm sorry for my English - I'm not a native speaker

Comment: May be its because your system is slow. Wait for sometime and if its still the same reply this comment.

Comment: Can u provide your system specs?

Comment: I waited a little bit but no change. And as for specs - I've got new rig recently (Core i5, nVidia geForce GTX 1060).

Comment: I found a hotfix here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979288

Please confirm before installing.

Comment: #PSN - I have Windows 10 and this is for Win Vista. I don't want to ruin my system by installing it.

Comment: I'm using VS2015 and it works fine.

Comment: On my old PC, it has run just fine, but I haven't got access to it anymore. And I'm really wondering what that "dong" sound means.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it can't be solved by re-install VS2015. It was solved after I TRULY uninstall VS2015 by the tool: https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases